# Maya MEL scripting sprintf equivalent

Tags: scripting, mel

How do you print an integer into a string in Maya MEL scripting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out you can just use `+` to concatenate string and integer objects in Maya Embedded Language.

For example:

```
int $i ;
string $s ;

    for( $i = 0; $i < 5; $i++ ) {
        $s = "ooh" + $i ;
        print $s ;
    }
```

There is also the [format](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2010help/Commands/format.html) command